# Android app is getting hanged , generating the following Logcat

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-logcat

I am working on a program for object detection , which is working fine . But the app is getting hanged after Detecting the object . This is the logcat of the app . the line specified with "I/Started" , tell the different states of the program .

The program is getting hanged after printing this statement "I/Started ( 2433):   System in Human Servoing State ".

```
I/Started ( 2433):   Current State of system 400
I/Started ( 2433):   System in wait state waiting for user to tap for servoing 
I/Started ( 2433): calling native opencv. state = 4
I/Started ( 2433):   Current State of system 400
I/Started ( 2433):   System in wait state waiting for user to tap for servoing 
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 21ms+2ms, total 59ms
I/InputReader(  341): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.25 ]
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/Started ( 2433): calling native opencv. state = 4
I/Started ( 2433):   Current State of system 400
I/Started ( 2433):   System in wait state waiting for user to tap for servoing 
I/Started ( 2433): calling native opencv. state = 4
I/Started ( 2433):   Current State of system 400
I/Started ( 2433):   System in wait state waiting for user to tap for servoing 
I/InputReader(  341): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/Started ( 2433): calling native opencv. state = 5
I/Started ( 2433):   Current State of system 500
I/Started ( 2433):   System in Human Servoing State  
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 41ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 37ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 14ms+8ms, total 55ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 52ms
W/PowerManagerService(  341): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x3
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 454K, 14% free 7391K/8519K, paused 15ms+2ms, total 51ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 14% free 7389K/8519K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 28ms
D/dalvikvm(  341): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1987K, 20% free 17766K/22087K, paused 20ms+7ms, total 149ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 58ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7391K/8519K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 42ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 14% free 7389K/8519K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 41ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7391K/8519K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 40ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 35ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 49ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7392K/8519K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 39ms
V/AlarmManager(  341): waitForAlarm result :8
V/AlarmManager(  341): ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
W/AlarmManager(  341): FACTORY_ON= 0
D/STATUSBAR-Clock(  454): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
D/STATUSBAR-Clock(  454): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
D/widget  (  609): [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> WC:477 [0:0]  mSHandler syncDM 
D/widget  (  609): [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> SM:1213 [0:0] bTCC WCV = 200
D/widget  (  609): [MSC_HERO_Accu_Tab]>>> WC:1650 [0:0] drw 2nd Tm dt = 1306
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7391K/8519K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 38ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 35ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 14ms+7ms, total 57ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 14ms+7ms, total 55ms
D/dalvikvm(  341): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1983K, 20% free 17765K/22087K, paused 9ms+8ms, total 134ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 435K, 14% free 7373K/8519K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 14ms+4ms, total 56ms
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7390K/8519K, paused 15ms+3ms, total 49ms
V/AlarmManager(  341): waitForAlarm result :1
V/AlarmManager(  341): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
W/AlarmManager(  341): FACTORY_ON= 0
D/dalvikvm( 1880): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 14% free 7410K/8519K, paused 11ms+16ms, total 63ms
W/AlarmManager(  341): FACTORY_ON= 0
I/System.out( 1880): boot -> stop
D/ApplicationPolicy(  341): isStatusBarNotificationAllowed: packageName = com.advancedprocessmanager
D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(  341): Noti Alert - mSystemReady:true, AlertEnabled:true
D/PhoneStatusBar(  454): addNotification score=0
I/System.out( 1880): onDestroy
W/ResourceType(  454): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x01030068 which is invalid or in a cycle.
W/ResourceType(  454): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x01030067 which is invalid or in a cycle.
W/ResourceType(  454): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x010301f2 which is invalid or in a cycle.
D/StatusBar(  454): expanding top notification at 1entry.userCollapsed() = false
E/Watchdog(  341): !@Sync 3
W/ThrottleService(  341): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
W/SocketClient(  101): write error (Broken pipe)
W/AlarmManager(  341): FACTORY_ON= 0
I/InputReader(  341): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.26 ]
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
E/lights  (  341): write_int failed to open /sys/class/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x0
I/PowerManagerService(  341): Ulight 0x3->0x7|0x0
D/LightsService(  341): setLightLocked is called
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x0
I/InputReader(  341): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x1
I/InputDispatcher(  341): Delivering key to current input target: action: 0x1
D/KeyguardViewMediator(  341): setHidden false
V/WindowManager(  341): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=1); user=1 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false sensorRotation=-1
I/GuideMe::Activity( 2433): onPause
I/GuideMe::SurfaceView( 2433): releaseCamera
D/SecCameraCoreManager(  113): virtual void android::SecCameraCoreManager::stopPreview():stop IT Policy checking thread
E/CameraHAL(  113): (4007bf30)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/espresso/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1792 setState - Adapter state switch PREVIEW_ACTIVE Invalid Op! event = 0xf
E/CameraHAL(  113): (41ca2738)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/espresso/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1709 setState - Adapter state switch INTIALIZED_STATE Invalid Op! event = 0x5
D/SecCameraCoreManager(  113): SecCameraCoreManager destroyed: pid=113
I/ShotSingle(  113): ShotSingle destroyed: pid=113
I/ShotCommon(  113): ShotCommon destroyed: pid=113
I/SecCameraCoreManager(  113): Destroying camera 0
I/CameraHAL(  113): Received NOTIFIER_EXIT command from Camera HAL
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): reset
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): cancel player events
V/OMXNodeInstance(  113): calling destroyComponentInstance
V/OMXNodeInstance(  113): destroyComponentInstance returned err 0
V/OMXNodeInstance(  113): OMXNodeInstance going away.
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): reset
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): cancel player events
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): reset
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): cancel player events
I/AudioSink(  113): +++ close
I/AudioSink(  113): --- close
W/AudioFlinger(  113): session id 10 not found for pid 113
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): reset
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): cancel player events
V/OMXNodeInstance(  113): calling destroyComponentInstance
V/OMXNodeInstance(  113): destroyComponentInstance returned err 0
V/OMXNodeInstance(  113): OMXNodeInstance going away.
I/AwesomePlayer(  113): reset
```

Comment: Maybe you could post some code?